# Como colocar o endereço no marker maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps

Boa Tarde Galera, tenho o seguinte codigo abaixo e gostaria de saber como faço para incluir o endereço no marker, pois eu possuo a lat e lng no banco de dados de todos os pontos. (Isso e um gps)

```
var image = '../assets/img/ambulance.png';
var map;
var markers = [];
var zoomLevel = 12;
var centerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.4745571, -46.5359114);
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();




function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
 center: centerPos,
 zoom: zoomLevel
};
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"),   mapOptions);
  var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  trafficLayer.setMap(map);

}

function setMapOnAll(map) {
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  markers[i].setMap(map);
}
markers = [];
}
```

> NESSE TREXO E NA ONDE EU DECLARO O QUE VAI APARECER NO MARKER, POREM EU QUERIA CONVERTER A lat e lon que esta gravado no banco em endereço;

```
function doLoad() {
 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'dispositivos/db.php',
 data: {
   action: 'getPos'
},
cache: false,
dataType: "json",

success: function(retorno) {

  setMapOnAll(null);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker;

  for (var i = 0; i < retorno.length; i++) {

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(retorno[i].lat, retorno[i].lon),
      map: map,
      icon: image
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        var iwContent = '<div id="iw_container">' + '<div class="iw_title"><b>' + retorno[i].responsavel + '</b></div>' + '<div class="iw_content">' + '<b>Data/Hora:</b> ' + retorno[i].cadastro + '</b></div>' + '<div class="iw_title">' + '<b>Telefone:</b> ' + retorno[i].numero + ' </b></div>' + '<div class="iw_title">' + '<b>Endereço:</b> ' + retorno[i].lat + ' </b></div>' + retorno[i].lon + '   </div></div>'; 

        infowindow.setContent(iwContent);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }

    })(marker, i));

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.close();
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }

},
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  //alert(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest, null, 2));
}
});
}

function cityByLatLng(latitude, longitude) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
  geocoder.geocode({
  'location': latlng
}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[0]) {
    document.getElementById('seu elemento').value =  results[0].formatted_address;
  } else {
    window.alert('No results found');
  }
  } else {
   window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
 }
});
}


 function FormatNumberLength(num, length) {
   var r = "" + num;
   while (r.length < length) {
    r = "0" + r;
   }
   return r;
 }

 function atualiza() {
   var d = new Date();
   var hora = FormatNumberLength(d.getHours(), 2);
   var min = FormatNumberLength(d.getMinutes(), 2);
   var seg = FormatNumberLength(d.getSeconds(), 2);
   $("#txtTime").val(hora + ':' + min + ':' + seg);
  doLoad();

  }

// Initialize when page loads
jQuery(function() {
initialize();

setInterval(function() {
  atualiza();
}, 5000);

  $('#full').click(function() {
   $('#mapCanvas').fullscreen();
   return false;
  });


 $("#btnCarregar").click(function() {
  atualiza();
 })
 });
```